# How to automatically cleanup orphans after updating corresponding attribute in parent?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a User model with (links to S3) images associated to it

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, :dependent => :destroy
  # left out other attributes for simplicity of the example
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :url, :name, :bucket
end
```

I have a JSON API to update images (/users/:id). A example POST request with JSON body looks like this:

```
{
  "user": { 
    "images": [
        {
            "name":"Fun pic",
            "bucket":"pix3.mydomain.com"
        },
        {
            "name":"Hilarious pic",
            "bucket":"pix2.mydomain.com"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to overwrite all images for that user with this new array, without leaving trace of the old images in the database.

Currently, I map all the image hashes in the array to Image object by using Image.create(hash). Let's call the resulting array 'new_images'. Then I call User.update_attributes({"images" => new_images }). The user will now have the correct images assigned to him, but the previous images are still floating around in the database.

So, I'm looking for a simple way to replace all objects in a has_many assocations by new objects, without leaving the old objects in the database. Of course I could create a transaction, delete all the old images first and then assign the new ones, but it seems like a lot of boilerplate. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the documentation from [Api dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many)

```
collection=objects

Replaces the collections content by deleting and adding objects as appropriate. If the :through option is true callbacks in the join models are triggered except destroy callbacks, since deletion is direct.
```

So when you do

```
user.images = new_images
user.save
```

This will destroy the old ones associated with user and update the user_id on the new_images in a transaction

Comment: Tried this and it works as expected :) I am using user.update_attributes(hash), since 'hash' can contain a lot of updated properties in my case. For the has_many relations I now use explicit assignment and filter those keys out using user.update_attributes(hash.except("images")).

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this approach:

```
@user.images.destroy_all  #destroy all the images that were associated with the user
@user.images = new_images #set the new array of images
@user.save                #commit changes to the object
```

May be a little dirty, but will definitely work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is more or less what I do now, although I basically use @user.update_attributes(hash) instead since 'hash' can contain a lot of updated properties. @Vimsha is right, you don't need to explicitly destroy the images, AR will do this for you. I will accept his answer.